# "Rate of traffic exceeds capacity" error on Google Cloud VertexAI but only sending a single prediction request

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As In the title. Exact response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Rate of traffic exceeds capacity. Ramp your traffic up more slowly. endpoint_id: <My Endpoint>, deployed_model_id: <My model>.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
```

I send a single prediction request which consists of an instance of 1 string. The model is a pipeline of a custom tfidf vectorizer and logistic regression. I timed the loading time: ~0.5s, prediction time < 0.01s.
I can confirm through logs that the prediction is executed successfully but for some reason this is the response I get. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider:

1. Allow your prediction service to serve using multiple workers
2. Increase your number of replicas in Vertex or set your machine types to stronger types as long as you gain improvement

However, there's something worth doing first in the client side assuming most of your prediction calls go through successfully and it is not that frequent that the service is unavailable,

Configure your prediction client to use `Retry` (exponential backoff):

```
from google.api_core.retry import Retry, if_exception_type
import requests.exceptions
from google.auth import exceptions as auth_exceptions
from google.api_core import exceptions

if_error_retriable = if_exception_type(
exceptions.GatewayTimeout,
exceptions.TooManyRequests,
exceptions.ResourceExhausted,
exceptions.ServiceUnavailable,
exceptions.DeadlineExceeded,
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,  # The last three might be an overkill
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError,
auth_exceptions.TransportError,
)


def _get_retry_arg(settings: PredictionClientSettings):
return Retry(
    predicate=if_error_retriable,
    initial=1.0, # Initial delay
    maximum=4.0, # Maximum delay
    multiplier=2.0, # Delay's multiplier
    deadline=9.0, # After 9 secs it won't try again and it will throw an exception
)

def predict_custom_trained_model_sample(
project: str,
endpoint_id: str,
instance_dict: Dict,
location: str = "us-central1",
api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
):
...
    response = await client.predict(
    endpoint=endpoint,
    instances=instances,
    parameters=parameters,
    timeout=SOME_VALUE_IN_SEC,
    retry=_get_retry_arg(),
)
```